# Why Android devices won't read NFC tags after a long sleep?

Tags: android, nfc, lockscreen

I'm sorry for my bad English.

I develop an Android app using NFC. I added a method that stops unsecured keyguards temporarily to the app for the purpose of quickly uses NFC tags.
However, I thought stopping keyguards causes battery drains when sleeping, so I added a method that recovers keyguards when devices are sleeping.

As a result, I wrote codes shown below.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private NfcAdapter      mAdapter;
private PowerManager    mPowerManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // regist screen on / off actions receiver
    IntentFilter scFilter = new IntentFilter();
    scFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    scFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    scFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
    registerReceiver(mScreenReceiver, scFilter);
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action != null && (action.equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)
            || action.equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED)
            || action.equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED))) {
        // manage NFC Tags here
        Log.d("MainActivity", "NFC Tags detected");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NFC Tags detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // enableForegroundDispatch
    if (mAdapter == null) { 
        mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    }
    if (mAdapter != null) {
        Intent nfcIntent = new Intent(this, getClass());
        nfcIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, nfcIntent, 0);
        mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, null, null);
    } else {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "failed getDefaultAdapter()");
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (mPowerManager != null) {
        if (!mPowerManager.isScreenOn()) {
            // clearWindowFlags only when device is sleeping
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        }
    }

    // disableForegroundDispatch
    if (mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
        mAdapter = null;
    }

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    try {
        // unregist screen on / off actions receiver
        unregisterReceiver(mScreenReceiver);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return false;
}

private BroadcastReceiver mScreenReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction() == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
        }
    }
};
}
```

But, this code didn't perform as intended on my device.
I use Nexus 7 (1st, OS 4.3, Slide lock enabled).

First, when I launched the app and put my device into sleep, keyguards didn't recover with a probability of 30%. It sounds read sound effects with NFC tags even when sleeping.

Second, my device rarely won't read NFC tags after about an hour sleep with using the app. It will not even sound anything with NFC tags. But the condition goes off after sleep again or terminating the app.

Who does know causes of the bugs?